# Java Servlet session management, how to create session for login

Tags: servlets, httpsession

I am working on a small webapp for fun, using just Java Servlets at the moment. I have two pages, test1 and test2. At the moment I am creating a new session in test1 like this:

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    if (session.isNew() == false) {
        session.invalidate();
        session = request.getSession (true);
    }
```

In test2 I am retrieving the session like so:

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session == null) {
        throw new ServletException ("No session.");
    }
```

So the problem is that if I go to test2 first, I am always getting a valid session because the browser creates one. I want to restrict the flow from test1 to test2 so that I have to go to test1 first. My plan is to eventually create a login page that will create the session, but the problem I am seeing here would still be present.

How should I handle this? I would like any ideas to not include 3rd party libraries. I'm doing this as a learning exercise.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I may be using Session here wrong. I am trying to restrict page flow, and will be later creating a login page that will, I think, invalidate the current session and create a new one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This makes no sense. Forget the `request.getSession(boolean)`. Just get the session by `request.getSession()` and never worry about the nullness/validness.

If you want to pass data through session attributes, then just do in `test1`:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("test", "foo");
```

and in `test2` (which is of course requested in the **same** session *after* `test1`):

```
String test = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("test"); // Returns "foo".
```

As to using the session to check the logged-in `User`, just do something like in the login code:

```
User user = userDAO.find(username, password);
if (user != null) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
} else {
    // Show error?
}
```

and then in a [`Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which is mapped on a `url-pattern` which represents the restricted area, just check if the `User` is present or not:

```
if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("user") != null) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // Just continue.
} else {
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("login"); // Not logged-in, redirect to login page.
}
```

and when you logout, you just remove the `User` from the session:

```
request.getSession().removeAttribute("user");

// Or, more drastically:
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

Alternatively you can also take a look for declarative [Container Managed Security](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#getting-started-securing-web-applications) with help of some simple entries in `web.xml` and the `server.xml`. This way you don't need to hassle with login/filter logic yourself.

#### See also:

- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-sessions-shared-variables-and-multithreadi)
- [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database)
- [Authentication filter and servlet for login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274279/authentication-filter-and-servlet-for-login/)

Comment: I'm not looking at just passing data back and forth, but using it as a security mechanism. Perhaps I am using the session wrong entirely?

Comment: Thanks. That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: So to make this easier, I should probably put all of my "restricted" content into a sub source folder, that way I can apply the filter to the whole thing.

Comment: Exactly :) You can for example use `url-pattern` of `/protected/*`, `/secured/*`, `/admin/*`, etc and place the content there. That's also less or more the way container managed security is supposed to work. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to restrict the flow to ensure that test1 comes before test2, have test1 put an attribute value in the session that says it's been visited, and test for that attribute value in test2. If the value is not there, have test2 redirect to test1.

In test1, do this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("test1",true);
```

Then, in test2, you can do this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if (session.getAttribute("test1") == null){
    response.sendRedirect("test1");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A session is just a basket that starts out empty. The concept of whether a user is authenticated or not is separate from whether or not the user has a session.

Java EE and the servlet specifications handle all the login stuff for you, redirecting to login pages and so on. Read up on the built-in capabilities of Java EE. Maybe start [here](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/Security5.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am definitely going to read up on this.

Answer (score -1):

When someone login with right credentials set a secession with this
`request.getSession().setAttribute("user", "user");`

now, you can check in this session user already present or not with this

`if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("user") != null)`

and you can delete the session at the time of logout

`request.getSession().invalidate();`

this work perfectly

NOTE:
import HttpServletRequest and pass request parameter like this

`import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;`

`public home(HttpServletRequest request){}`