# How to create session for login and logout in java

Tags: java, jsp, httpsession

This is the code that I have written in login page

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("name", user1);        
String nme=(String) session.getAttribute("name");
```

And, This is the  code for **logout.jsp**

```
<% request.getSession().invalidate();
```

OR

```
if(session!=null){
   session=null;
}
```

OR

```
 request.getSession().setAttribute("name", null); //it just assigns null to attribute

 response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
 %>
```

session is creating, But after logout button is working....
I want that back button should not work.

Comment: Browser's back button will load the page from its cache(no request to server). So the server side validation won't work here.

Comment: The session variable should be checked on the server side, so it should not be relevant as to whether the user pushes the back button or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java session management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835764/java-session-management)

Answer (score 6):

To logout or invalidate from the current session, you have the correct code in place, as below.

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

Now, after you hit the back button of the browser, it is loading the page from the cache. So in order to take care of this situation you can do below 2 things.

1. Manipulate the browser history using HTML 5's `History` API so that when you click the back button it goes to the desired location as you manipulate it.
2. Suggest user to close the page, as general secured websites do after successful session logout, like bank websites & financial websites.

Alternatively, you can write & configure an interceptor class in servlet container/server end to manipulate the cache by adding below parameters in the response.

```
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: HttpServletRessponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();

Comment: You need to do this in an interceptor and not in the JSP. Interceptor will intercept the response and write these parameters before JSP receives the response. If you do this in JSP then it will not have any effect on the cache as you are doing this after JSP has already read & processed it.

Comment: ServletActionContext giving error. I think it is in struts. right

Comment: Yes, I had already corrected the example. You need to get hold of response object based upon your application architecture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63396/discussion-between-shishir-kumar-and-madhavi-talla).

Answer (score 0):

just remove the attribute from session, and check if it exists.....

```
request.getSession.removeAttribute("name")
```

and check like:

```
if(request.getSession.getAttribute("name")==null){

}
```

Comment: request.getSession.getAttribute does not return a boolean

Comment: @MadhaviTalla this is not the code to disable the back button, but by doing this check previously logged-out user will not be able to sign in again into the system by pressing back button or refreshing the page.

Comment: @MadhaviTalla actually disabling the browser back button is really not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with the session, as it will not be used in page that has already been loaded and simply loaded from the cache (back button functionality)

Consider utilizing `localtion.href.replace` in you client code.

> localtion.href.replace(url):Replace the current document with the one
>   at the provided URL. The difference from the  assign() method is that
>   after using  replace() the current page will not be saved in session
>   history, meaning the user won't be able to use the Back button to
>   navigate to it.